# Kubernetes: What kinds of system aspects should I inspect in the endpoint that serves my readiness probe

Tags: kubernetes

I have a simple SpringBoot application (really a REST-based microservice) that I am deploying in Kubernetes.

It has one downstream dependency (another REST-based web service).
I know that for the REST endpoint feeding the ***liveness*** probe I should not return a failure if my downstream dependency is unavailable / inaccessible (as Kubernetes restarting my microservice pod won't fix the dependency!).

But in the REST endpoint feeding my ***readiness*** probe should I be checking downstream dependencies? I'd rather just do something basic but if I need to be checking more then I will.

```
@RequestMapping("/health")
public String getHealth() {
    return "OK";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming, the liveness of your spring-boot app (user's perspective) does not require the dependent service to be up, your idea of checking the status of the Readiness Probe is a right thing to do.

As the dependent app is a REST service, you could expose an HTTP/HTTPS endpoint to be checked by the *readiness probe*. And keep spring-boot app's health check (or similar) endpoint for *liveness probe*.

However, beware that your pod which runs first microservice (spring-boot app) could become unresponsive if the dependent service didn't respond.

Therefore, providing correct timeouts (initialDelays & periodDelay) with success and failure thresholds help you mitigate such unresponsive status. For example;

```
readinessProbe:
  httpGet: # make an HTTP request to dependent's health/readiness endpoint
    port: <port>
    path: /health
    scheme: HTTP 
  initialDelaySeconds: 10 # how long to wait before checking
  periodSeconds: 10 # how long to wait between checks
  successThreshold: 1 # how many successes to hit before accepting
  failureThreshold: 3 # how many failures to accept before failing
  timeoutSeconds: 15
```

The official doc: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-probes/#define-readiness-probes

A good article: https://itnext.io/kubernetes-readiness-probe-83f8a06d33d3

Comment: "your idea of checking the status of the Readiness Probe is a right thing to do." - did you mean "your idea of checking the status of the downstream dependencies in your Readiness probe is a right thing to do."? Or did I misunderstand?

Comment: Hi @kellyfj I meant that use of a readiness probe as you described is a right thing to do.

Answer (score -1):

Ideally you should consider all those component of application which participate in request processing. It can be backend, some configurations, job status etc. The goal is very simple, if readiness probe is successful your application is fully ready to serve any request.

So design readiness probe accordingly but always keep it as lightweight as possible as and it should not consume more resources than required.